# Do Protractor tools as similar as Cypress features exist?

Tags: protractor, cypress

Currently, I use Protractor for my project. But I discover Cypress and I'm falling in love with some feature like auto-loading tests and testing GUI that allow to see screenshot for each steps.

I search some tools similar for Protractor but nothing. Does someone know some tools like that, please ?

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

To screenshot after each step you can use [protractor-html-reporter-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-reporter-2)

and set option screenshotsOnlyOnFailure to false.

> screenshotsOnlyOnFailure (bool) default: true To display screenshots
>   only in testcases that failed. Default value is "true".

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know this dependency. 
I will read that but if possible, I want to take screenshot every step and have an ergonomic interface to read them.